# Sinatra: run ruby code when a URL is hit

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to run a script (code.rb) every time the url /code is hit.

How do I run the script?

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  #run the script
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either fork off another process:

```
system('ruby code.rb')
```

... or simply `load` the script into the current context:

```
load 'code.rb' # *not* require
```

Comment: Given that yours is the accepted answer, may I suggest that you should update it to suggest `load` instead of `require`, per my answer?

Answer (score 6):

You need to `load` the code to ensure that it is run each time; `require` will only load the code once on the first request, and then not again:

```
smagic:Desktop phrogz$ cat hi.rb
  puts "hi"

smagic:Desktop phrogz$ cat test.rb
  require 'sinatra'
  get '/require' do
    x = require_relative( 'hi.rb' )
    "require sez #{x}"
  end

  get '/load' do
    x = load( 'hi.rb' )
    "load sez #{x}"
  end

smagic:Desktop phrogz$ ruby test.rb 
  == Sinatra/1.1.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
  >> Thin web server (v1.2.7 codename No Hup)
  >> Maximum connections set to 1024
  >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
  hi
  127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2011 20:49:43] "GET /require HTTP/1.1" 200 16 0.0019
  127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2011 20:49:46] "GET /require HTTP/1.1" 200 17 0.0005
  hi
  127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2011 20:49:52] "GET /load HTTP/1.1" 200 13 0.0009
  hi
  127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2011 20:49:54] "GET /load HTTP/1.1" 200 13 0.0008
  127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2011 20:50:09] "GET /require HTTP/1.1" 200 17 0.0005
  127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2011 20:50:12] "GET /require HTTP/1.1" 200 17 0.0005
```

The output of `hi` comes before the request entry in the log; you can see that the requests to 'require' only output `hi` the first time, while requests to 'load' show `hi` each time. Here's the output of the server, where `true` indicates that the code in the file was actually run and `false` shows that it was not:

```
smagic:~ phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/require
require sez true

smagic:~ phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/require
require sez false

smagic:~ phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/load
load sez true

smagic:~ phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/load
load sez true

smagic:~ phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/require
require sez false

smagic:~ phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/require
require sez false
```